# Как вывести данные по диапазону дат одного столбца (с такого по такое)? C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Всем привет, у меня есть код для всплывающего окна где я должен указан диапазон дат для столбца DATE_D (с какого по какое должны выйти данные в таблице), как мне правильно обозначить это в коде? сейчас у меня выходят данные только за один день, который указывается в первом условии

```
        if (Cond.Success)
        {
            string Conditions = "";
            // условие по дате C
            var date_d = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<DateTime>("DATE_D");
            if (date_d != null)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " cast(PWREG.DATE_D as date) >= cast(@date_d as date) ";
            }
            // условие по дате ПО
            var date_to = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<DateTime>("DATE_D");
            if (date_to != null)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " and cast(PWREG.DATE_D as date) <= cast(@date_to as date) ";
            }
            // условие по сотруднику
            var n_kdk = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<string>("N_KDK");
            var rcentr = Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<string>("RCENTR");
            if (n_kdk != null && n_kdk.Length > 0)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " and PWREG.N_KDK = @n_kdk ";
            }
            // условие по рабочему центру
            if (rcentr != null && rcentr.Length > 0)
            {
                Conditions = Conditions + " and PWREG.RCENTR = @rcentr ";
            }
            return new SqlCmdText(string.Format(Conditions),
                new SqlParam("n_kdk", n_kdk.ToString()),
                new SqlParam("rcentr", rcentr.ToString()),
                new SqlParam("date_d", date_d),
                new SqlParam("date_to", date_to));
        }
```

Comment: Вы используете одно и то же выражение `Cond.InputFormValues.GetValue<DateTime>("DATE_D")` для обеих дат - и для начала, и для конца диапазона..

Comment: Черт, действительно, я все это время использовал значение date_d которое указано у меня для начала даты, спасибо, это была глупая ошибка)